# Use of "in" in a function's arguments

Tags: swift, function, parameters, keyword

I have been following the Ray Wenderlich book *Advanced iOS App Architecture*, and they have a protocol that looks like the following:

```
protocol RideOptionDeterminedResponder {
  func pickUpUser(in rideOptionID: RideOptionID)
}
```

I don't understand the us of `in` before the `rideOptionID` parameter (which, by the way, is just a typealias for String), as I always thought you only used this keyword when writing closures. I've looked around a lot for uses of `in` but haven't had any luck.

What is the purpose of `in` here, and how would the function be different if it were absent?

(If you need more information on how this function works in order to explain yourself better, just let me know.)

Comment: It just makes for prettier code. When you call the function, you would write `pickUpUser(in: someId)` which can look prettier than `pickUpUser(rideOptionID: rideOptionID)`.

Comment: And if you replaced `in` with `_` then you would call the function like `pickUpUser(someId)`

Comment: Thank you to all. I appreciate your quick support! If I could mark both answers as accepted I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions in Swift support both an external and an internal name. This effectively means you can refer to the same parameter using two different names. That's what `in` is in the code you provided, an external parameter name.

The difference between external and internal parameters is that you use the first when calling a method, and the second when dealing with the value inside such method's body.

So, you would call the method as such:

```swift
// Call the method using the external parameter name in
pickUpUser(in: someRideOptionID)

func pickUpUser(in rideOptionID: RideOptionID) {
  // Do something with the value, accessing it using the internal parameter name rideOptionID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `in` keyword here is only meant to specify the argument in the function. While calling the function you can just call it as:

```swift
pickUpUser(in: rideOptionID)
```

If `in` was not present, you'll have to call it as:

```swift
pickUpUser(rideOptionID: rideOptionID)
```

You can go through the [Swift Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) for more detail on `Specifying Argument Labels`